How to download qr code with some text below
I have to download qr code with some name like i have to download whole view with qr code and text its downloading qr code but not the view with text this is what it's downloading and second picture describe what i want to download.
const downloadQrcode = async () => {
try {

  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(

    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,

    {

      title: 'Storage Permission',

      message: 'This app needs access to your storage to download QR code.',

      buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',

      buttonNegative: 'Cancel',

      buttonPositive: 'OK',

    },

  );



  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

    qrCodeRef.current.toDataURL(async (data) => {

      const fileName = `QRCode_${Date.now()}.png`;

      const path = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/${fileName}`;

      await RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, data, 'base64');

      alert('Download Successful');

    });

  } else {

    alert('Storage permission denied');

  }

} catch (err) {

  console.error('Error downloading QR code:', err);

}



                <View style={styles.qrCodeContainer}>

                  <QRCode

                    value={selectedRegistrationID}

                    size={200}

                    getRef={(ref) => (qrCodeRef.current = ref)}

                    logo={fullName}

                  />

                  <Text style={styles.idStyle}>{selectedRegistrationID}</Text>

                  <Text style={styles.idStyle}>{fullName}</Text>

                </View>

              </View>

I have tried viewshot but it's not downloading image.

I see what looks like JavaScript code, and something to do with Android permissions? If this is react-native, consider adding the tags [javascript] [android] [react-native] to your question.
